# Understanding LW in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

What is the value in `$t2`?

```
LUI $t1, 0
ORI $t1, $t1, 16
LW  $t2, 8($t1)
```

Firstly, I think that the equation is `rs = offset + base` address,
`8 + 16 = 24`.

However, my professor said it is wrong.

I think I do not fully understand `LW`. Could you help me to solve the problem and extra concept of `LW`?

Comment: The question makes no sense to me. `$t0` is not used anywhere in the code you've posted.

Comment: Based on [this](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) I would say you are right, `$t1` is `0x10` and `$t2` contains the word at `0x18`. However, `$t0` doesn't seem to be touched anywhere? (I'm just guessing, I have no experience with MIPS, all I did was look at the linked link)

Comment: @JustSid: 16 is 0x10.

Comment: @Michael  Ouch, thanks! I was at the 8 for whatever reason (which is also wrong). I guess I should go back to bed.

Comment: LUI only loads into the upper part of t1. What was in the t1 in the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$t1 = 0x10
$t2 = (0x18)
```

That is, the value stored at `0x18` will be loaded into `$t2`.

`LW` means Load Word. It loads a word into a register from the specified address. `0x18` is the address, not the value that will be stored into `$t2`.